# Using shell to list contents of a directory in a specific manner

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a program that lists the number of files, sub-folders and softlinks in a given directory in shell bash. 
The program should take prerequisites and use them as the input. So $1 would be the directory you wan to list the contents of.
It should also be able to display only files or only softlinks using 
-f (for files), -l(for softlinks) and -d(for directories within the specified dir)

Alright Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

function funk {

for i in $1; do

        counttotal=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -printf .            |wc -c);
        countdir=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf .      |wc -c);
        countfile=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf .     |wc -c);
        countlink=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf .     |wc -c);
        echo " : $i   [Total:$counttotal] [Dir:$countdir | Files:$countfile | Links:$countlink]"
        done
}

function justfile {

for i in $1; do
        countfile=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf .     |wc -c);
        echo " : $i  [ Filer:$countfile ]"
done
}

function justdir {
for i in $1; do
       countdir=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf .      |wc -c);
        echo " : $i    [ Dir:$countdir ]"
done
}

function justlink {
for i in $1; do
        countlink=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf .     |wc -c);
        echo " : $i   [ Links:$countlink ]"
done

}
```

Now I had an if-statement below this that would check if $1 was nothing and would then run funk in the working directory. Then it would check if $1 was -f and if so it would run onlyfile. Else it would just run funk in the dir you gave it.

However I see now that this is a very inefficient method of doing this and would mean that I would have to have at least 5 if-statements in one ...

I have been looking around for a way to do this and stumbled across 'shift'and it seems like the way to do this...

But I am very unsure of how to go about using it and would be very thankful for some help.

Comment: What you should use here is [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can use `getopts` or can use the following pure bash solution :

```
echo Usage : script.sh -f file <or> script.sh -d dir
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    key="$1"
    case "$key" in
        -f|--file)
        shift
        ARG_FILE="$1"
        ;;
        -d|--dir)
        shift 
        ARG_DIR=1
        ;;
        *)
        FLAG_CURRENT_DIRECTORY=1
        ;;
    esac
    # Shift after checking all the cases to get the next option
    shift
done

# Process further based on the options
```